# Install dependency jar file in apache-karaf-2.3.10

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

I am trying to deploy an bundle in Apache karaf-2.3.10 container which inturn has jar file dependencies. After copying the dependency jar file to deploy dirctory of Apache-Karaf dependency issue got resolved. How to install the normal jar through command line. I tried the below command

```
osgi:install -s 'wrap:mvn:<path to the jar file/test.jar>'
```

which shows

> Error executing command: Error installing bundles:

My bundle has lot of dependency jar files. Do i need to copy all the jar files to deploy directory? If, it will become messy. 
Is there any other way to point the location or creation a config file so that in activation bundles dependencies will be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and this is normal for OSGi applications. 
For this you can use features with Apache Karaf. 
So please take a look at the corresponding documentation:

[Apache Karaf Provisioning and Features](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/users-guide/provisioning.html)

a wrapped bundle in a feature might have the following "wrapped" maven coordinate:

```
<bundle>wrap:mvn:my.group.id/my.artifact/version</bundle>
```

Regarding Features Repositories, those can be of any kind, as long as the link to the repository (Feature file) can be navigated to. For Example the following are valid "coordinates":

```
file:/filesystem/to/my/so/awesome/features.xml
https://remote.Link.to/my/so/awesome/features.xml
mvn:my.group.id/my.artifact/version/xml/features
```

If your local maven repository does contain a features maven artifact it will be treated as the one to look for.

Feature repositories are added by:

```
feature:repo-add mvn:my.group.id/my.artifact/version/xml/features
```

via karaf shell. Or added as "bootfeature" while building custom Karaf. 
Again, more details can be found in the documentation.

Comment: It's normal for *all* applications to have to install their dependencies. Not just OSGi apps... all Java apps... heck, any app written in any language!

Comment: @Neil The problem is i am having lot of dependency jar files. Is there any way to configure altogether similar to installing feature in Karaf. Because wrap is giving error which i mentioned in the question!

Comment: As I said use feature files, and use the wrap with it. Per default the wrap URL handler is installed in karaf.

Comment: @Achim is it possible to map a local maven repository as repo using features:addUrl?